# Setting version for my flutter app in build.gradle file

Tags: flutter, dart, version-control

I am getting ready to release my app for testing. I have looked into the versioning of my app and found that it is done in the app/build.gradle file. I need to know if what I have is sufficient of should I change it manually?

Here is the build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Should I leave this code in place or should I have something like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode "1.0"
        versionName "1.0_beta"
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing directly on `app/build.gradle`, you can use `local.properties` file. Also other files will be needed to generate release apk

[image]

More about [android deployment.](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android)